# Chronicle map using primitives

Tags: java, latency, chronicle, chronicle-map

In `Chronicle-map` description it is said:

> Chronicle Map provides in-memory access speeds, and supports ultra-low garbage collection. Chronicle Map can support the most demanding of applications.

What does ***supports ultra-low garbage collection*** actually stand for? Does it mean that the Chronicle map tries to allocate as few objects as possible in heap?

As far as I know, projects which have low latency requirements try to avoid unnecessary allocations, partly by using gc-free collections, partly by object pooling. One of them is avoiding unnecessary boxing/unboxing of the primitives. For example if you have a `Map<Long, Entity>`, to avoid creating `Long` objects, you can use map implementations based on value types, like `TLongObjectMap<Value>` in `trove` library.

Then it would make sense to make it possible to create `chronicle-map` instance in such manner, using primitives as keys, for example. Is it possible? If not, are there any reasons behind not implementing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible to use `ChronicleMap` without making a single allocation (i. e. garbage) on the hot path. If you have primitive keys (or values), you should use flyweight pattern facilitated by [Chronicle Values](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Values) library. See [Value interfaces instead of boxed primitives](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/master/docs/CM_Tutorial.adoc#value-interfaces-instead-of-boxed-primitives) section in the tutorial.

Comment: Would koloboke also worth looking at.